# Convert bitset<64> to quint8

Tags: c++, binary, bitset

I have a `bitset<64>` (16bit serial and 48bit timestamp), which I want to write to `quint8 *data` .

When the `bitset<64>`looks like:

```
1111001010100101...
```

I want `data` to look like:

```
data[0] = 11110010
data[1] = 10100101
...
```

Would be thankful if somebody could help me to implement that.

Comment: Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Finally, [a `std::bitset` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) could be helpful. There are ways to get a 64-bit integer out of your bitset, which can then be used to copy the bits to your array of bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly then this accomplishes what you ask:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

int main()
{
    std::bitset<64> bits64{0b0111101111011001110011010101110001111011110110011100110101011100};

    /*
    01111011
    11011001
    11001101
    01011100
    01111011
    11011001
    11001101
    01011100
    */

    for (auto i = 7; i >= 0 ; i--)
        std::cout << std::bitset<8>{bits64.to_ullong() >> (i * 8)} << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
01111011
11011001
11001101
01011100
01111011
11011001
11001101
01011100
```

You can change the `for` loop statement to make it emit in whatever ordering of bytes you choose.

The key thing is employing [the *shift* operator](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.shift#2) (`<<` or `>>`) on the integral value.

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks a lot !